# Is battery temperature reading, dependent on the ROM that is installed on the phone

Tags: battery

On my original Android installation, the battery temperature was 31-37°C depending on what I was doing. Now I've installed a custom ROM and the temperature is usually 35-41°C.

This 4°C difference is something that I should feel with my hand, but I doubt there is that much difference.

Is it possible that two different ROMs are reading the same temperatures differently?

PS: Power consumption is not much different either

Comment: You are not going to feel a 4C difference with your hand.